# Is there a way to concurrently share a drive on multiple devices

Tags: linux, usb-drive

I'm looking to allow one device to read and write to a drive, while another device has read only access. I do not have access to make modifications to the device that has read and write access. For example, the primary device writes logs to a USB. My custom secondary device could read those logs and upload to a server. Maybe some sort of USB raid setup?

Comment: The question is a bit vague. Yes, you could mount it, export it via NFS, or Samba, even sshfs and use it wherever it has to be used. Any network filesystem would do, either directly or via nbd or iSCSI for example.

Comment: Thanks. How would I mount it on both devices concurrently?

Comment: You just mount it **once** and then export it via a network filesystem, that can be mounted multiple times for reading, writing or both. But that's just one way of solving what. Without more details ... it's hard to answer. It could be a lot simpler too. It's not clear why you are using and USB drive in the first place.

Comment: **If (!)** your drive's filesystem allows for it, you might just use `ACL`s and access the drive through a different user with read or readwrite access, respectively. If it is just two (or three) devices, differentiation between user/group/others might already suffice.

Answer (score 0):

From your question it appears that you have something like this:

```
[ DEVICE A ]--- USB ---[ STORAGE ]
```

and you want to be able to read [STORAGE] from another device, B. It is doable, **but not at all simple**.

You **CANNOT** do this with a standard device and your stated limitations ("Cannot access or modify device A").

You need to go another, *much* bumpier road. You need a custom USB device capable of acting as a storage device, *and also* of sharing its storage with device B. This can be done with, e.g., a [Raspberry Pi 4](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/100583/where-is-the-usb2-otg-port-on-the-rpi-4-model-b-located) or any other OTG capable device. Then, the Raspberry has to be connected to a suitable storage device (e.g. a SSD or a SATA, with the appropriate "hat"), and configured to share the storage device through Samba.

Comment: Thanks. I started going that route but the Pi seemed to lockup if both devices were using the drive. Maybe I didn't share via Samba? I'll give it another go, I was probably doing something wrong. Do you have a good guide that you could recommend for this?

Comment: I have heard that there may be power issues. I'd start with connecting via SSH to the Pi4, and see what happens when Device A writes its logs. There is also a speed issue, whereby it's best to connect to the Pi4 through a wired interface rather than USB WiFi. See here for the power topic: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/102385/can-a-raspberry-pi-4-be-used-as-usb-gadget-but-draw-power-from-elsewhere

Comment: Got it thanks. I'll try give it another try.